# ScrollView scrolls even beyond content when it shouldnt

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have an Activity whose layout has a scrollview as root element. The problem I am facing is that, the scrollview scrolls even beyond content. For Example: If we have little content on the screen which can be placed within the window, the scrollview shouldnt scroll even a bit. I have changed the `android:height` value to both `wrap_content` and `match_parent` but still no success.

Note: I have this scrollview inside a ViewPager

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mcd_bg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_icon_pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_button" />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#f4c104"
            android:textSize="32sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_menu_list_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:text="@string/back_button_text"  />
        </RelativeLayout>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#f4c104"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flag"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/burger_largw" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price_tag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_circle_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_option_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/special_request_edittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/textview_white_bg"
                android:hint="@string/special_request_hint_text"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_literal_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quantity_literal_text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/quantity_value_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:text="@string/default_item_quantity" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/decrease_quantity_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/minus_button" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/increase_quantity_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/plus_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_to_cart_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/addtocard_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One of your LinearLayouts has `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. Not sure if that is causing the issue or not, but looked strange since everything else was `"wrap_content"`.

Comment: changed to `wrap_content` still doesnt work

Comment: Tried setting layout_height="0dp" on the LinearLayout?

Comment: I think you will have to tear the layout apart and slowly try to narrow down what is causing the behavior. I suspect you might have to add weights to some of the layouts contained within the outer LinearLayout. I would think the 0dp and weight 1 on the outer and a lower weight on the inner layouts might be a possible solution but cannot give a clear answer.